# JLabel keeps its position when jframe maximized

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlabel

I have jLabel with an icon wanna put in right top corner , in Netbeans design view I place it to a desired position , After running program it is stay there fine ! But when I maximize the window it doesn't horizontally move to the corner and keep its position. It becomes like in the middle.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any idea, how the code is generated for this in the background?

Comment: What `LayoutManager` are you using?

Comment: i am using netbeans default layout manager mattise

Comment: any other layout managers ?

Comment: Matisse is not a [`LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html), it is a part of the IDE that *uses* layout managers to size and position components.  All JSE layout managers are in the `java.awt` package and the `javax.swing` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a design tool to create the GUI. Its sounds like Netbeans is using a absolute layout which is not what your want.

Use a proper layout manager. Maybe a `FlowLayout` that is `right aligned`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Flow Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: @user3498019, I have no idea. I don't use an IDE. I would rather spend my time learning how to use Java instead of learning how to use the IDE. Read the tutorial for information.

Comment: go and learn java , no body is a border on you to learn java , instead of complaining , post an answer if you know java before suggesting somebody to learn java

Comment: @user3498019, I don't understand your comment. I DID post an answer.

Comment: @ camickr you said  " I would rather spend my time learning how to use Java instead of learning how to use the IDE. " then come and answer questions